# Environmental causes of module.__init()__ takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) ? - python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, nose, nosetests

I have two machines with my python module installed on it (the module is a series of selenium tests)

To run the test suite, I call `python runner.py --user <user>`

On the first machine, everything works fine.  On the second machine I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes a most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

This is not a code issue becuase the code on these two machines is the exact same - I install the module via a .whl

What environmental issues could cause such an error?

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: TypeError (Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
 addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\seleniumTestSuite\speed_loading_settings_45672_tes
    t.py", line 23, in <module>
    class Settings_LoadQuickly_45672(unittest.TestCase):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the exact same versions of the packages and python on both machines?

Comment: Did you run the program with Python 2.7 on both machines?

Comment: The successful machine is using 2.7.9, the failing one 2.7.10.  I will try downgrading and see if that works

Comment: No dice.  Both machines are running 2.7.9 with the same issue. And both packages are the same version as well.

Comment: What is the full stack trace? And the relevant code for that?

Comment: Added stack trace.  I get the exact same stack trace over and over again for 160 tests, with only the class name changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, figured it out -- the top `__init__.py` in my module had been **deleted** from the failing machine.

```
MyModule
    __init__.py   <-- This was deleted!!
    Lib
        __init__.py
        <core_py_files>
    Tests
        __init__.py
        <test_files>
    Settings
        __init__.py
        <settings_files>
    test_runner.py
```

Hope this answer helps someone else, because that error is super non-transparent.